# How does the compareTo method work for Strings? if a word comes after another word in the alphabet then it returns positive or negative?

Tags: java

Let's say i write this:

```
String a = "Hello";
String b = "Goodbye";
int compare = a.compareToIgnoreCase(b);
System.out.println(compare);
```

What will the printout be?

Comment: https://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#compareToIgnoreCase-java.lang.String-

Comment: I get **`1`**. What happened when you ***tried*** it?

Comment: Why can't you run the code and find out yourself?

Comment: Or you could [search for similar questions](https://www.google.com/search?q=java+how+does+String+compareto+work+site:stackoverflow.com)

Answer (score 0):

It compares character by character for each string.

For example in this case
When a = "hello" and b = "Goodbye"

It checks first character of a with first character of b and computes the relative difference, if it's same then it checks the next character, else it computes the difference and returns it.
If string a is greater than string b it returns a positive difference else it returns a negative difference.

Answer (score 0):

in this case the out are be **1**, because **H** comes after of **G**